# How to hide third party keyboard in ionic Framework

Tags: android, ios, typescript, ionic-framework, mobile

I am using ionic 3 for my application. I would like to hide third party keyboard on client phone. basically want to disable option to use third party keyboard. I would like to show only native keyboard. Will it be possible to do that. if yes, what are the recommended ways in ionic framework. Thank you so much.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, there is no way to do this.  The user has the absolute right to choose his keyboard.

Secondly-  you shouldn't ever do this.  How do you know the native keyboard supports his language?  Maybe he's sight imapaired and using a keyboard that reads out keys?  Maybe he has motor skills issues and uses a motion based keyboard (when working at Swype we got letters from several people with disabilities who said they could only use our keyboard).  There are good reasons why some people need to use third part keyboards.  Even if you found a way to do it, there's no valid reason to do so and you may well be harming your users.

Thirdly-  there is no "native keyboard".  Every OEM has the right to install their own keyboard as default.  Google's keyboard doesn't ship on every Android device-  several OEMs buy keyboards from 3rd parties, and several others develop their own (Samsung at least used to write their own based on the Swiftkey SDK).

Comment: Thank you so much for good explanation. I also can't find any valid solutions so far as well and everyone is suggestion not a good way to do this.